# Building a FAQ chatbot with FAQ data of different companies

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I am trying to build a FAQ chatbot that should be trained to answer questions about FAQ's of four different companies. I have FAQ data of 4 different companies. I want to build a chatbot using Rasa that are trained on data of each of these companies(includes same question and different answer from 2 different companies). If it is unable to respond to a queston, it should transfer it to a human. How should I approach this problem. Shall I create only one chatbot or multiple instances of 1 chatbot for the same? Any responses on the same will be very helpful.

Comment: I don't know what Rasa is, but I googled it and this came up: https://www.datasciencelearner.com/how-to-build-a-chatbot-rasa-complete-guide/
Good luck! We can help with specific errors, but you have to show some code and effort first. :)

Comment: Hi, few statements are a bit unclear. Could you explain further what you meant by the following statement: "(includes same question and different answer from 2 different companies)" ?

Answer (score 0):

If they are from the same domain, you could have just one RASA chatbot for all. And handle the responses in your back-end application(using API) based on which company the user is referring to. Although I would strongly suggest having different chatbots for different companies to avoid rework later.